# Image Uploading Python

Tags: python, html

I wants to browse image & upload image to folder in my application using python

when i click  on submit button its shows me http://www.domain.com/store_mp3_view & image is not uploaded

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="/store_mp3_view" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="mp3">Mp3</label>
    <input id="mp3" name="mp3" type="file" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**python file code**
import os
import uuid
from pyramid.response import Response

def store_mp3_view(request):
     # `filename` contains the name of the file in string format.
    #
    # WARNING: this example does not deal with the fact that IE sends an
    # absolute file *path* as the filename.  This example is naive; it
    # trusts user input.

```
filename = request.POST['mp3'].filename

# ``input_file`` contains the actual file data which needs to be
# stored somewhere.

input_file = request.POST['mp3'].file

# Note that we are generating our own filename instead of trusting
# the incoming filename since that might result in insecure paths.
# Please note that in a real application you would not use /tmp,
# and if you write to an untrusted location you will need to do
# some extra work to prevent symlink attacks.

file_path = os.path.join(/files, '%s.mp3' % uuid.uuid4())

# We first write to a temporary file to prevent incomplete files from
# being used.

temp_file_path = file_path + '~'
output_file = open(temp_file_path, 'wb')

# Finally write the data to a temporary file
input_file.seek(0)
while True:
    data = input_file.read(2<<16)
    if not data:
        break
    output_file.write(data)

# If your data is really critical you may want to force it to disk first
# using output_file.flush(); os.fsync(output_file.fileno())

output_file.close()

# Now that we know the file has been fully saved to disk move it into place.

os.rename(temp_file_path, file_path)

return Response('OK')
return Response('OK')
```

Comment: this isn't even correct python code. Put some debug code in your function and see what happens.

Comment: Is this Django or something similar? You should tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use models filefield inside models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', max_length=5234,blank=True, null=True,)
```

corresponding forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='', show_hidden_initial='none',required=True,)
```

Inside views.py

```
if request.FILES.has_key('your_fileName'):
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['your_fileName'])
            newdoc.save()
```

I got it working with above code, hope it helps

Comment: will have to include model, forms, views python files ? & your_fileName means which file?

Comment: yes user3322102 you have to include model,forms and views.  **docfile** which we used in model & form

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can upload multiple files

```
def insert_file(self):
    for i in request.FILES.getlist('mp3'):
        fileName = i.name
        out_file = open(fileName,'w')
        out_file.write(i.read())
    return HttpResponse('Inserted Successfully')
```

Comment: @user3322102,check my above answer,That may work for you